# Django Forms: No 'field errors' or 'non field errors'. But is_valid returns false

Tags: python, django, django-forms

views.py

```
form1 = Form1(temp_arg=obj)
form2 = Form2()
if request.method == 'POST':
    print "submitting form"
    form1 = Form1(request.POST)
    form2 = Form2(request.POST)
    print form1.is_valid             # prints false
    print form2.is_valid             # prints true
    print form1.errors               # prints None
    print form2.errors               # prints None
    print form1.non_field_errors()   # prints None
    print form2.non_field_errors()   # prints None
    if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
        print "form is valid"        # not executed
        #some code form.save and all
    else:
        print "Error!"               # prints this
```

forms.py

```
@parsleyfy
class Form1(ModelForm):
def __init__(self, temp_arg, *args, **kwargs):
    temp_val = temp_arg
    super(Form1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['field1'] = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=get_field_choices(temp_val))
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
```

I have two forms. 1 form contains a choice field that need to be loaded dynamically. I wrote a function `get_field_choices` for that and called it from the  `__ init __`  function of the form. It was working perfectly until I added temp_argument to this. Now the problem is that  the form with dynamic loading function is not getting validated. But `form.errors` and `form.non_field_errors` returns nothing. I am unable to trace what is wrong with the form.

Comment: I found the answer myself.

instead of `form1 = Form1(request.POST)`, I used 

`form1 = Form1(temp_arg=obj,data=request.POST)`. And it worked.

Comment: `form1.is_valid` <-- this is not going to do what you think.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid: Can you explain?
Any way I got the answer and the code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `form1 = Form1(request.POST)`, I used

`form1 = Form1(temp_arg=obj,data=request.POST)`. And it worked.